# Customized Removed state "Wont Fix" is visible in the work item hub (Azure Devops) - We do not want to see it, is there a way?

Tags: azure-devops, settings, workitem

Customized Removed state "Wont Fix" is visible in the work item hub - We do not want to see it, is there a way?

We have added a customized removed state as "Wont Fix", we do not want to see this in the work item hub as it clutters the list.

I see from this article https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/removed-items-shouldnt-appear-in-my-work-items/365975 there was a fix for this but this is not working if we add a customized state under removed state.

Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KMTC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SLZl.png)

I see from this article https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/removed-items-shouldnt-appear-in-my-work-items/365975 there was a fix for this but this is not working if we add a customized state under removed state.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that you can see the Removed category state in "Recently updated" View.
[image]

You could refer to the official doc: [View work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/view-add-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#view-work-items) for more details.

The thread you referred to: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/removed-items-shouldnt-appear-in-my-work-items/365975 is indicating that when the user chooses the option to see items "Assigned to me", the removed state work item should not be listed.